# Tomcat Solr times out

Tags: centos5, solr, tomcat

(Plesk 10.4 centos 5.8 linux apache2 server, with Tomcat5 on port 8080 and Apache Solr)

I get "The connection has timed out" on requesting domain.com:8080 or www.domain.com:8080 or ip.ad.dr.ess:8080

Every reason I can find why this might be seems not to be the case:

- Plesk thinks Tomcat is running fine and lists it as an active
  service.
- The firewall currently has an accept all rule on port 8080.
- There's nothing relevant in the catalina tomcat logs (/var/log/tomcat5) - just
  some stuff from last time tomcat was started. There's no record at all of the requests that fail.
- `netstat -lnp | grep 8080` gives the following, which I *beleive*
  means Tomcat is listening to requests to port 8080 on all ip addresses from any ip and any port (please correct me if I'm wrong):

:

```
tcp     0      0 0.0.0.0:8080       0.0.0.0:*     LISTEN      4018/java
```

This covers every cause of this time out that I can find - so I must be missing something fundamental.

It seems Tomcat is running, listening to the right port, is getting an appropriate IP address, is not obstructed by a firewall and is not failing after receiving a request in a way which would be recorded in the logs (so I believe it can't be out of memory, or anything like that).

I'm all out of ideas on how to continue debugging this. I must have overlooked something obvious. Can anyone help?

Comment: It might be worth adding that Tomcat was installed correctly, and that it and Solr were working fine a few weeks ago. Then I found Tomcat and Solr had stopped, so I restarted it and also added an autostart script for Solr. Both seemed to work fine, no errors on either, but the same URLs that worked before now just time out. AFAIK nothing else has changed since then. Hope that helps. Any ideas, debugging tips, alternate log files to check... any clues are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it turns out there are firewalls, and then there are *firewalls*.

I'd niavely assumed that setting an allow access rule on the port in the Parrallels/Plesk/VZ firewall UI was enough to stop the firewall blocking access to that port. I was wrong, this UI does not touch a wholly seperate layer of firewall based on iptables, which was blocking access to 8080 for all but selected IPs.

In my Plesk set up (which might be specific to my hosting arrangement, I'm not sure) the solution was to add rules to `/etc/firewall/include` that look like this:

```
$IPTABLES -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -s ip.ad.dr.ess -j ACCEPT
$IPTABLES -I OUTPUT -p tcp --sport 8080 -d ip.ad.dr.ess -j ACCEPT
```

...followed by `service firewall restart` (swapping ip.ad.dr.ess for the ip addresses you want to whitelist). I'm pretty sure in most hosting arrangements you could just run those lines as commands with `/sbin/iptables` instead of `$IPTABLES`, but having a file of custom firewall settings is pretty handy.

I guess this is a case of "If you give a man a crutch (like Plesk), he'll assume he can lean on that crutch"

Comment: Handy command for seeing iptables-based access rules for a port: `iptables -nL OUTPUT |grep 8080`